# Unsupervised classification of images

Tags: classification, python, unsupervised-learning, computer-vision, anomaly-detection

Assuming I have a dataset of images from two similar classes, for example let's say 95% Labradors and 5% of Chihuahuas and I want to make a classifier. The point is that I need to find the anomalies (Chihuahuas in this example). What would be a good approach that would be quite easy to implement (in *python* or, to be even more specific, in *pytorch*)?

I thought about using a neural network with convolutional layers in order to get features, and after I get a list of features use k-means to do clustering. It should work, I guess, but I'm not sure how to integrate k-means into the net. I vision conv layers that give features, I feed those features into k-means (or any other clustering technique) and then what? How do I close the loop with the net that I want to train?

I thought about other approaches too, like maybe using PCA on the features and then do the clustering (/classification), maybe use SVM, or even SOM (convolutional SOM, though I'm not sure I'd find much about it over the net).

Let's sum this up?

1. How do I integrate a clustering technique into a NN?
2. Is there any other good (and simple) approach that I can use?
3. Keep it simple. I need a simple solution that is easy to implement, not the best solution/results.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "using the NN to get features". Initially you need to define the input features beforehand, and these are the ones you would use for the initital clustering before you run the NN?

Comment: I see a big problem with your approach, as there is no way to define a loss function for your neural network unless you already had your images clustered, and there is no way of clustering your images without the help of an already-trained neural network

Comment: Have you investigated using autoencoders? I don't have much experience with them, but my understanding is that they are a NN approach that can be unsupervised.

I have had a few colleagues get good results with PCA.

Comment: @Edgar I'll make it clearer - When we feed an images to a NN we get features from the conv layers, which we feed to FC and then use a softmax layer. 
What I meant is to get features from the conv layers, feed them to FC layer and then integrate  a "clustering layer" into the network so the network will learn how to "find the anomalies".

Comment: @David I intend to use a pretrained network , that's what I was thinking.

Comment: @KitterCatter I believe autoencoders will give quite bad results.
PCA is an option, though I'm not sure yet how exactly to implement that and I prefer use a NN for that.

Comment: The first conv layer would just aggregate the information from the images. You could run a clustering algorithm on these convoluted features (I have no idea how well this works). Subsequent layers of the NN depend on the labeling of the images, so you cannot use them for clustering (because the clustering gives you these labels).